# Longtable and threeparttablex in Classicthesis

Tags: longtable, classicthesis, threeparttablex

I am using `classicthesis` to typeset my thesis, and I use the default library template.

I am using `longtable` to create a big table, and `threeparttable`to create footnotes in table. But, the table created is not distributed in two pages.

The code I used:

```
\begin{threeparttable}

{\footnotesize
    \centering
    \begin{spacing}{0.65}
    \begin{longtable}{p{0.06\linewidth}
                      p{0.18\linewidth}
                      p{0.05\linewidth}
                      p{0.17\linewidth}
                      p{0.14\linewidth}
                      p{0.07\linewidth}
                      p{0.06\linewidth}}

   \caption{Esta de arte en Sistemas BCI para comunicación alternativa en sujetos sanos.}\\
        \hline
        \bfseries Fuente & 
        \bfseries Paradigma & \bfseries SOA\tnote{a} & \bfseries Característica & \bfseries Clasificador & \bfseries Acc.\tnote{b} & \bfseries ITR\tnote{c} \\
        \hline
        \endhead

        %
        % Table contents
        %

   \end{longtable}
   \end{spacing}


\begin{tablenotes}
    \item[a] .
    \item[b] .
    \item[c] 
\end{tablenotes}

}
\end{threeparttable}
```

The compiler result:

[image]

I think that `longtable` divides the table, but can not move to the next page.
How can I solve that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Remove the brace before `\footnotesize` and the correponding closing brace. Also remove the `spacing` environment.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the welcome.  I made the changes you suggested, but the problem persists.

Comment: You also need `\begin{ThreePartTable}` and `\end{ThreePartTable}, not `threepartable`.

Comment: @egreg The problem was solved. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @egreg Do you want to make that an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using the `threeparttablex` package. Remove the brace before `\footnotesize` and the corresponding closing brace; also the `spacing` environment should be removed: if you need it, use the declaration form.

Most importantly, the outer environment should be `ThreePartTable`. Note the special capitalization.